# relative transformation of coordinates on a flat surface

Tags: geometric-transformation

I have a few coordinates that form a triangle. I have a relative point to that triangle. if the coordinates get translated to a new triangle I want to calculate the new relative point. How do I do this generally not only for 2 dimensions but for larger ones too?

```
# triangle translation
(5, 2) -> (2, -3)
(2, -3) -> (-3, 6)
(-3, 6) -> (6, 5)
# relative point
(5, -7) -> (x, y)
how do I solve for x, y?
```

[image]

EDIT: as I've done more research into basic geometric transformations I can see that I'm asking for a generalization of all possible transformations of the space. This is not merely a rotation, or a dilation, etc. This particular example rotates the space then stretches it in various ways. So what is the generalized solution for calculating spatial transformations? What are the steps to solve for X?

EDIT AGAIN: thinking about this intuitively I think there might be two answers to the question: one where the 2d space is not rotated and one where it is.

[image: space is translated then stretched around the center of the traingle]

[image: space is rotated around the center of the triangle]

I think the first, straightforward solution is the one I'm looking for. But I don't know how to compute it. But if the case can be made that the second rotational solution is more generalized maybe I'd rather use that, idk. I think I'd be happy with either solution.

Can you help me?

Additional Edit:

Here is the starter code I have produced from John Hughes linear transformation calculation below.

```
def extrapolate(domain_coordinates, result_coordinates, point):
    '''
    given a set of input coordinates and their resulting
    coordinates post-transformation, and given an additional 
    input coordinate return the location (coordinate) in the
    post-transformation space that corresponds to the most
    logical linear transformation of that space for that
    additional point. "extrapolate where this point ends up"
    '''
    import numpy as np

    # Add the number 1 to the coordinates for each point
    domain = [(x, y, 1) for x, y in domain_coordinates]

    # Do the same for the "target" coordinates too
    result = [(x, y, 1) for x, y in result_coordinates]

    # Put these coordinates, arranged vertically, into a 3×3 matrix
    domain = np.array(domain).T
    result = np.array(result).T

    # D^−1 is the "matrix inverse"
    inverse = np.linalg.inv(domain)

    # Let M=RD^−1
    matrix = result * inverse         # why do I need M?...

    # Do the same for the extrapolation point
    xpoint = [(x, y, 1) for x, y in [point]]
    xpoint = np.array(xpoint).T

    # extrapolate ???
    extrapolated_point = matrix * xpoint    # this isn't right...

    return extrapolated_point


extrapolate(
    domain_coordinates=[(5, 2), (2, -3), (-3, 6)],
    result_coordinates=[(2, -3), (-3, 6), (6, 5)],
    point=(5, -7))
```

This code is not working right, for instance, if I insert this test just before the return...

```
    print(domain * np.array([[1],[0],[0]]).T)
    print(domain * np.array([[1],[0],[0]]).T * matrix)
```

it prints...

```
[[5 0 0]
 [2 0 0]
 [1 0 0]]
[[ 1.73076923  0. -0.]
 [-0.57692308 -0.  0.]
 [-0.34615385  0.  0.]]
```

whereas I would expect it to print...

```
[[5 0 0]
 [2 0 0]
 [1 0 0]]
[[ 2  0.  0.]
 [-3  0.  0.]
 [-1  0.  0.]]
```

as per this statement:

> Then multiplication by the matrix R will take A to A′

Can you show me where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're referring to **linear** transformations (informally: those that take straight lines to straight lines), and that you only want to consider those that are invertible (i.e., that don't send everything to a point, or to a single line), here's your answer. It also works for $n+1$ points in $n$-space (here you have three points -- A, B, C -- in 2-space).

Step 1: add the number 1 to the coordinates for each point, so you have

```
coordinate rewrite:
(5, 2) -> (5, 2, 1)
(2, -3) -> (2, -3, 1)
(-3, 6) -> (-3, 6, 1)
```

Do the same for the "target" coordinates too. 
Put these coordinates, arranged vertically, into a $3 \times 3$ matrix:

```
coordinate rewrite:
(5  2  -3) 
(2 -3   6) 
(1  1   1)
```

And call that matrix $D$ (for "domain"). If you multiply D by the three standard coordinate vectors, the results will be your three (rewritten) original points; for example,
$$
\pmatrix{
5 & 2 & -3 \\
2 & -3 & 6 \\
1 & 1 & 1
}
\pmatrix{0\\1\\0} = 
\pmatrix{2 \\-3\\1}.
$$
By the way, the three standard coordinate vectors are usually called $e_1, e_2, e_3$, where $e_i$ has a "1" in position $i$, and zeroes elsewhere. This generalizes nicely to higher dimensions.

So now we have $De_1 = A, De_2 = B, De_3 = C$, where $A,B,C$ denote your original points, but with the extra "1" at the bottom.

Do the same thing for the "target" points to get a matrix $R$ (for "result"):
$$
R = \pmatrix{
2 & -3& 6 \\
-3 & 6 & 5 \\
1 & 1 & 1}
$$

By the same argument, we have $Re_1 = A', Re_2 = B', Re_3 = C'$, where $A'$ denotes the "new" location for $A$, again with a $1$ appended, i.e., 
$$
A' = \pmatrix{2\\-3\\1}.
$$

Now comes the fun part: Let
$$
M = RD^{-1}.
$$
Then multiplication by the matrix $R$ will take $A$ to $A',$ and $B$ to $B'$, and $C$ to $C'$. You can also multiply $X$ (your "extra point", but with a "1" appended) by $R$ to get $X'$ (the new location of the "extra point", from which you'll want to delete the extra "1" at the bottom).

It's possible you'll find yourself asking "What does $D^{-1}$ mean?" and the answer is "it's the matrix inverse," and you can read all about it in any linear algebra book. If you're writing software, a great many matrix libraries have an "inverse" operation. Small warning: computing $D^{-1}$ is generally expensive. IF you're hoping to transform a bunch of "X" points, compute $RD^{-1}$ once, and then use it over and over, rather than recomputing each time.

Comment: in step 1 do you mean to say: (2, -3) -> (2, -3, 1)?

Comment: Also, does this answer perform a linear transformation according to the origin or according to the center of the triangle? probably the origin right? so if I want to do it from the center of the triangle I'll have to just make that my origin first? See my image #2. Furthermore, I'm not quite following this answer 100% though I can tell this is what I need. and, Yes I am doing this for some software written in python.

Comment: I've fixed that type with the $(2, -3, 1)$. As for your second comment...there is exactly one "affine transformation of the plane" (i.e., transformation preserving lines, but not necessarily sending the origin to the origin) that takes A,B,C to A', B', C', and I've written it down for you. I've implemented that affine transformation as the restriction of a *linear* transformation of 3-space to the $z = 1$ plane, but that doesn't really matter. What matters is that if you want a (continuous) lines-to-lines map that sends those 3 points to the other 3, this is it.

Comment: If you show me the starting point for some python code (especially what things you're importing), I might be able to help out further.

Comment: Well, the starting code I had in python took a completely different approach, I was attempting to get the ratios between all points in terms of distance along the X and Y axes, averaging those points to give me a small triangle which I would then get the center of and that would be my X location. so. I couldn't get that to work, so I need to translate the math speak you have here (which I don't speak) into code, I'll put what I have for this new approach so far in the question as an additional edit, but it won't be much at all. I appreciate any and all of your help!

Comment: I've added more code to my attempt. I'm failing to understand what you're saying here at the very end. M=RD−1. Why do I need to compute M? You say multiplication by the matrix R will take A to A' etc. in the example code I must be doing something wrong because I don't get those kinds of results, and therefore I can't extrapolate X correctly. Do you see where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to double-check all my arithmetic, but here's a valid strategy.

If $x$ is mapped to $Ax+b$ for square matrix $A$ and vector $b$, $A(\sum_iw_ix_i)+b=\sum_iw_i(Ax_i+b)$ provided $\sum_iw_i=1$. So we try to write$$\binom{5}{-7}=w_1\binom{5}{2}+w_2\binom{2}{-3}+(1-w_1-w_2)\binom{-3}{6}\iff\binom{8}{-13}=w_1\binom{8}{-4}+w_2\binom{5}{-9}.$$This gives simultaneous equations in $w_1,\,w_2$, with solution $w_1=\frac{7}{52},\,w_2=\frac{18}{13}.$Since $1-w_1-w_2=\frac{-27}{52}$. So $\binom{5}{-7}$ is mapped to$$\frac{7}{52}\binom{2}{-3}+\frac{18}{13}\binom{-3}{6}-\frac{27}{52}\binom{6}{5}=\frac{1}{13}\binom{-10}{69}.$$